# Remove metadata using formidable

Tags: node.js, metadata, formidable

Just now I'm using formidable to upload photos to my node.js server.
The server is working good, but for some reason, when someone upload a photo from their iOS device and after that some other person see the same photo, the foto has a rotation by default.
First, I thought that the problem was the photo resolution, but then, I stored the same photo without metadata (with photoshop) and the photo with the same width and height is working correctly.
Then, my problem is only with the metadata of iOS devices.
Does someone have any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can strip all metadata from JPEG files using:

```
jpegtran -copy none
```

You can either do this with an on-disk file (add `-outfile`) or pipe an image to its stdin and get result on stdout.

In node you'd do that with `child_process`'s `spawn`.

Comment: are there any other packages that will allow me to remove the metadata from any file?